# How to specify throttling by individual user in WSO2 api manager?

Tags: api, wso2

I am currently trying out api manager (1.6).Is there a way to throttle each consumer of api to a specific limit (requests/seconds)?

I see an option to throttle at the publisher level (as a publisher) and at the application level (in api store) but it is not the same as specifying how much an api can be invoked by each subscriber

Also, what does application level throttling mean in the api store? Is it to specify how many total api calls can an application make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set tier permission to user roles (can be from the API Publisher). This allow you to define what tiers are available to users of a given role. So when a developer is trying to subscribe he will only see the tiers enabled to his role.

Application level throttling is to limit API access to all API's that are under a given application. For example you may have a Finance APP that would use multiple API's. you may want to restrict the finance APP from accessing only a limited number of API's. This can be done by setting a throttling limit to the application rather than to individual API's.

Answer (score 0):

You can not throttle each consumer but you can limit it in the subscription level. 
Subscriber can create more than one application and subscribe API with different throttle levels.